# WordPress swapping variables around?

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a function to handle the titles of the pages, posts, home page etc.. however I have run into a problem.

Here is the code in the Functions.php :

```
function theTitle() {

   $siteName = bloginfo('name');
   $sitePage = get_the_title();

   if (is_home()) {
        echo $siteName;
   }
   if (is_page()) {
        echo "(". $sitePage . ") &raquo; " . $siteName;
   }
}
```

When you are on the homepage, the title is:

```
<title>This is the title specified in settings</title>
```

However, when you go to an individual page the title is:

```
<title>This is the title specified in settings(About Us) &raquo; </title>
```

As you can see, it is outputting the **$siteName** first, instead of adding it to the end. Has anyone come across this before? Do you know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bloginfo()` echoes the return value of `get_bloginfo()`, so use `get_bloginfo()`.